# Как наследоваться от values v21 в v11?

Tags: android

Есть атрибут

```
 TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title
```

Который меняет цвет текста у АкшенБара. Но он работает с v13, а как же остальным быть?

Каким способом профи программисты наследуют values-v8 атрибуты из v13 и выше?

Comment: больше подробностей

Comment: @Andreich, Я программирую не так много, поэтому многих вешей не знаю. Форумчанин Surface сказал, что можно использовать возможности из новых апи в старых путем support libraly.

Я хочу поменять в своем приложении цвет текста в ActionBar, там, где название моей программы отображается, а также цвет самого ActionBara.

Нашел способ вписать в style.xml    

     TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title

Который меняет цвет текста.

Но беда в том, что IDEA говорит, что этот атрибут в API V13 начинается использоваться.

А как мне включить его в API V11?

Comment: @Futurama, вы используете tollbar? Если да, то гуглите, как поменять цвет title у него, если нет, то надо его начать юзать и затем снова прочитать это сообщение.